# Without BIND window tool is there any possible way to run the dig command using node js?

Tags: node.js, bind, dig

Without BIND tool is there any possible way to run  the dig command using node js or else is there any BIND package available in node which can run inside node the platform?

Comment: What is your question. Do you want to run the `dig` program without having it (download it for your platform) OR do you want a Node.js package that emulates the `dig` program?

Comment: i want Nodejs package that emulates the dig program

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic. Google search and select a DNS package. Once you have a programming problem, post your code, expected results and/or error messages.